# Troubleshoot NFS mount not working after reboot

Tags: centos6, nfs, mount, boot

I created a mountpoint and an entry in the `fstab`

```
 nas:/server1           /nas/server1           nfs     rw,_netdev 0 0
```

This should try to mount the nfs during startup; but it might fail. That is why I also enabled the `netfs` daemon:

```
 >sudo chkconfig
 ...
 netfs              0:off   1:off   2:off   3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
 ...
```

Current runlevel:

```
>runlevel
N 3
```

When rebooting, the mount does not work, not even after a while.

**What can I do to troubleshoot this issue?**

In `/var/log/messages` I only find one entry containing `nfs`.

```
Jun  7 16:14:51 bison kernel: RPC: Registered tcp NFSv4.1 backchannel transport module.
Jun  7 16:14:51 server1 kernel: Slow work thread pool: Starting up
Jun  7 16:14:51 server1 kernel: Slow work thread pool: Ready
Jun  7 16:14:51 server1 kernel: FS-Cache: Loaded
Jun  7 16:14:51 server1 kernel: NFS: Registering the id_resolver key type
Jun  7 16:14:51 server1 kernel: FS-Cache: Netfs 'nfs' registered for caching
```

This is the guide I tried to follow

http://thenubbyadmin.com/2013/04/10/solving-nfs-mounts-at-boot-time/

[EDIT:]

I found more information, in the `boot.log`:

```
Mounting filesystems:  mount.nfs: Failed to resolve server nas: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

So it seems the DNS is not working on boot-time. This makes sense, but I thought / assumed `netfs` would take take of this. However, I have been unable to find any `netfs` logging yet.

[EDIT 2]

`netfs` service was not running while it was configured in the `chkconfig`. Starting `netfs`  (`service netfs start`) manually restored the missing mounts.

[EDIT 3]
Maybe related: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1320570

Comment: And manually running `mount /nas/server1` does work?

Comment: `mount -a` works, so I assume `mount /nas/server1` will work as well

Comment: looks like you are trying to mount before network is fully functional:  **Failed to resolve server nas**